# Where can I get flexible ferrous/ferritic strip?

Tags: mounting, metal

It is easy to find narrow flexible strips that are magnetic on one side and sticky or smooth on the other side, commonly used to turn any object into a fridge magnet.

What I want to find is the opposite. A narrow flexible strip that is sticky on one side and ferrous/ferritic on the other side, so that magnets will stick to it. I want to turn a narrow section of wall into something that fridge magnets can be stuck to.

A strip of steel or iron is a slight option, but it's harder to ship, sharper on the edges, and more likely to rust.

Edit: the smooth white surface of the exposed side is an important feature of the existing product that I hope to duplicate in the product I'm looking for. I might settle for glossy or brushed metal, but I don't want the ugly grey/brown of the back of a magnet strip.

Comment: Magnets will stick to each other, so you could use a magnet strip on the wall.

Comment: @mbeckish edited my question to clarify that I don't want to sacrifice the smooth white surface.

Comment: You wanted a flexible strip; will this be applied to a flat surface, or a curved one? How large of a surface are you looking for?

Comment: @JasonAller right now, flat. I'm vaguely looking for 1"x96".

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** - Here are two sources for strips - [MyWhiteBoards](http://mywhiteboards.com/write-on-magnets.html) and [MagnetValley](http://www.magnetvalley.com/index.cfm/fa/subcategories.main/parentcat/26786/subcatid/77404). However these strips are magnetic but should be equal or better than "magnetic receptive" material.

**Original post** - It sounds like you want a surface similar to a dry-erase white board.  [MyWhiteBoards](http://mywhiteboards.com/dry-erase-wall-covering-magnetic.html) is a source for flexible, magnetic, dry-erase wall covering.  Although it is called "magnetic", it means "magnetic receptive" which means that magnets will stick but the covering itself is not magnetic.  From this source, the smallest size (1.5 ft x 2 ft) costs $42 and includes a peel-n-stick backing.

If a non-flexible surface is OK, then Office Depot or Staples carry lower cost magnetic-receptive white boards.